# Does any know what kind of pump "Colossus" used for saving the Notre Dame Cathedral?

Tags: pumps, robotics, fire

Does any know what kind of water pump the French Firefighting Robot Colossus used to Help Save Burning Notre Dame Cathedral?

What kind of water pumps do fire fighting vehicle use or fire fighting robots use?

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah I did. Most of the are very vague in terms of the specs.

Comment: High pressure water cannon - 660 gallons per minute.

Comment: Fire fighting pumps are typically just a version of centrifugal pump.  Most in the US are driver by a Power Take-Off ("PTO").

Comment: I saw pumps rated at 2600 rpm that deliver 1 litre per rev, can’t remember pressure rating though but it was high given the size of the device (1m*0.8m*0.3m) driving cooling water around thermal plants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a definitve answer, but since I went to the trouble to look it up I thought i might as well post what I found: Pretty sure there's no onboard pump

[image]

As you can see this is a normal firehose, not a suction hose with reinforcing spirals. this is relevant because it means water has to be supplied to Colossus at pressure, from a fire engine with a pump.

Next, let's look at the [published specs](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5df36a06aac1414fe3532950/t/6006ea0ee40b7c3f2c279ea1/1611065879941/Colossus+-+EN+.pdf) - no mention of a pump or water tank:

[image]

6 batteries, 48V and 27 Ah translates to roughly 7.7 kWh. Smallest fire pumps I found where around 20 kW - I don't think it makes sense to power a fire pump from a battery.

Water has to be supplied anyway, so at most Colossus would carry a small booster pump. I sum I think the best approach for Colossus and similar vehicles is simply to have a water supply at sufficient pressure, and not carry an onboard tank or pump.